# Toggling between display:none / display: block versus node.replaceWith()?

Tags: html, dom

EDIT: I didn't want to complicate the snippet further but I don't think it was illustrating the question very well. Now the snippet shows what the content is in each notebook container. The left-hand notebook always has three tabs in the DOM and the right-hand notebook has only one the selected tab in the DOM.

---

The following snippet is included as an attempt to make my question more clear; there's nothing special in it.

All I'm trying to ask is, What is the difference between toggling the `display` style to make a node in the DOM "visible" or "hidden" (I know it's not the same as the `visibility` style) and removing/adding the node from/to the DOM? Is there anything to be gained by keeping the DOM as simple as possible by removing/adding nodes from/to the DOM, or is removing/adding nodes from/to the DOM a more costly operation for the browser relative to maintaining a larger document?

This snippet just selects tabs in a notebook UI two different ways: the left-hand one, by using class 'sel' and the right-hand one, by replacing the tabsBody node.

Suppose the user were to add 500 tabs to the notebook, would keeping only one in the tabsBody in the DOM be superior to keeping all 500 with 499 set to `display: none`?

All 500 would still be in RAM but the DOM would be much smaller.

Thank you for considering my question.

```js
let ntbk_1, tabsMenu, tabsBtn, tabsBody, tabsMap_1, tabSel_1;

ntbk_1 = document.querySelector('.ntbk_1');
tabsMenu = document.querySelector('.ntbk_1 .tabsMenu');
tabsBtn = tabsMenu.children;
tabsBody = document.querySelectorAll('.ntbk_1 .tabsBody > div');
tabsMap_1 = new Map();
tabSel_1 = tabsBtn[0];

for ( let i=0, l=tabsBtn.length;
      i < l;
      i++ ) {
  tabsMap_1.set(tabsBtn[i],tabsBody[i]);
  tabsBody[i].dataset.i = i+1;
}

tabsBody[0].classList.add('sel');
tabsBody[0].textContent = printNodes(ntbk_1.lastElementChild.children);

tabsMenu.addEventListener( 'mousedown', navTabs_1, false);

function navTabs_1( evt ) {
  let t, e = evt.target;
  if ( !e.matches('button, button *') ||
       e === tabSel_1 ) return;
  tabSel_1.classList.remove('sel');
  (t = tabsMap_1.get(tabSel_1)).classList.remove('sel');
  t.textContent = 'Tab ' + t.dataset.i + ' Content';
  tabSel_1 = e;
  tabSel_1.classList.add('sel');
  t = tabsMap_1.get(tabSel_1);
  t.classList.add('sel');
  t.textContent = printNodes(ntbk_1.lastElementChild.children);
}

function printNodes(nodes) {
  let a = [];
  for ( let i=0, l=nodes.length;
        i < l;
        i++ ) {
    a.push( nodes[i].outerHTML.trim() );
  }
  return a.join('\r\n');
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------ */

let ntbk_2, tabsMap_2, tabSel_2;

ntbk_2 = document.querySelector('.ntbk_2');
tabsMenu = document.querySelector('.ntbk_2 .tabsMenu');
tabsBtn = tabsMenu.children;
tabsBody = document.querySelectorAll('.ntbk_2 .tabsBody > div');
tabsMap_2 = new Map();
tabSel_2 = tabsBtn[0];

for ( let i=0, l=tabsBtn.length;
      i < l;
      i++ ) {
  tabsMap_2.set(tabsBtn[i],tabsBody[i]);
  tabsBody[i].dataset.i = i+1;
}

tabsBody[1].remove();
tabsBody[2].remove();
tabsBody[0].textContent = ntbk_2.lastElementChild.innerHTML.trim();

tabsMenu.addEventListener( 'mousedown', navTabs_2, false);

function navTabs_2( evt ) {
  let t, te, e = evt.target;
  if ( !e.matches('button, button *') ||
       e === tabSel_2 ) return;
  tabSel_2.classList.remove('sel');
  (t = tabsMap_2.get(tabSel_2)).replaceWith(te = tabsMap_2.get(e)); 
  t.textContent = 'Tab ' + t.dataset.i + ' Content';
  tabSel_2 = e;
  tabSel_2.classList.add('sel');
  te.textContent = ntbk_2.lastElementChild.innerHTML.trim();  
}
```

```css
.ntbkCan {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ntbk {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300x;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.tabsMenu {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.tabsMenu button {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
  cursor: pointer;
}  

.tabsMenu button.sel {
  background-color: rgb(70,170,220);
  cursor: auto;
}  

.tabsBody {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.tabsBody > div {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  white-space: pre;
}

.ntbk_1 .tabsBody > div {
  display: none
}

.ntbk_1 .tabsBody > div.sel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ntbkCan">

  <div class="ntbk ntbk_1">
    <div class="tabsMenu">
       <button class="sel">Tab 1</button>
       <button>Tab 2</button>
       <button>Tab 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tabsBody">
      <div>Tab 1 Content</div>
      <div>Tab 2 Content</div>
      <div>Tab 3 Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ntbk ntbk_2">
    <div class="tabsMenu">
       <button class="sel">Tab 1</button>
       <button>Tab 2</button>
       <button>Tab 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tabsBody">
      <div>Tab 1 Content</div>
      <div>Tab 2 Content</div>
      <div>Tab 3 Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the [`hidden`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-hidden) attribute to show / hide an element.

> All HTML elements may have the hidden content attribute set.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("fieldset").toggleAttribute("hidden");
});
```

```html
<button>Click To Show / Hide Fieldset</button>
<br><br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fieldset</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation appears to state that the hidden attribute uses `display:none`. How does this relate to `display: none` versus having only the selected node in the DOM by using `repalceWith`?

Comment: I think the `find` feature in the browser will work if it's in the DOM. They say `Web browsers will use 'content-visibility: hidden' instead of 'display: none' when the hidden attribute is in the hidden until found state, as specified in the Rendering section.`